# objective c - starting Apples Maps or Google Maps on MapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, maps, mkmapview

i want to know how I can start other apps from my app.

Here the situation:

I have a MapView pointing to a specific longitude/latidude.

I want to give the user the chance to navigate (Google Maps or Apple Maps) themselves with this two apps to the coordinates.

So how can i:

1. Start another app (in this example GoogleMaps or Maps), check first which one is installed
2. pass them the long/lat coordinates?

i hope this is clear enough..

Comment: What are you trying to say? :-O

Comment: thanks for down vote, updated question..

Comment: Did you make any efforts to find answer of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**handleopenurl.com**](http://handleopenurl.com/) is a good website to get link of opening app directly from your apps. If you will search for Google Maps there it will show you an link something like this which includes lat/long in link only.

```
 routeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f&mrsp=0&ht=it&ftr=0", contactPosition.latitude, contactPosition.longitude, myPosition.latitude, myPosition.longitude];
```

(Also you will need [Google Maps SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) to incorporate in your app.)

[Now to check if Google Maps app is installed  or not you will use `canOpenURL` method to determine that. If app is not installed it will open Google Maps in Safari web browser.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:routeString]){

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:routeString];
            }
            else{
                self.urlGlobal=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&sensor=false"];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:self.urlGlobal];
            }
```

Comment: ty for that website and the code!